# Estimating Centre of Mass during Rotation

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics

I am considering the centre of mass of a gymnast who is jumping forward and following a trajectory in the air whilst also rotating.

If we consider a two-dimensional plane where the gymnast jumps forward in the $x$-direction, what is the best way to estimate the $y$-coordinate of the centre of mass over the entirety of the trajectory (the orientation of the body is known at certain times and the mass distributions associated to head, upper body, arms, thighs and legs may be estimated from the literature).

Answer (score 2):

The acceleration of the center of mass (CM) of the gymnast is determined by the total external force. Internal forces do not affect the motion of the CM, so the CM follows the same path no matter how the gymnast moves while in the air. The location of the CM with respect to say the gymnast's head can change as the gymnast moves, for example if the gymnast tucks legs and arms into a "ball".

The change in angular momentum with respect to the CM is determined by the total external torque with respect to the CM and is zero if gravity is the only external force.  The angular momentum about the CM remains as it was when the gymnast left the ground.  The angular velocity can change if the gymnast changes the moment of inertia with respect to the CM, for example by tucking legs and arms.

Comment: So for example if you jump forwards and go into a full tuck before landing, is the CM position shifted upwards?  What would be the easiest way to find the location?  I am thinking if one has an idea of the percentage of mass distribution located at the head and neck etc. one could estimate the CM position.

Comment: Once off the ground the CM moves as if the body is a point particle subject to gravity: a projectile. Tucking, or whatever, once in the air does not affect the position/path of the CM.

Comment: I'm happy with that, but can't the position of the CM change if you are in the body's reference frame?

Comment: The body frame is a non-inertial (accelerating) reference frame, and IN that frame all the CM is fixed. Fictitious forces must be accounted for to evaluate the motion in the body frame. One point of confusion.  If you read about Euler's equations for rotation of a rigid body they give the inertial torques in terms of the body frame coordinates.  The total torque in the non-inertial body frame where the rigid body is fixed is zero.  Here you do not have a rigid body.